# Failed to write manifest file.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain

Tags: react-native, error-handling, expo, sentry

I have react native expo app with Sentry configured. Sentry is reporting this crash.

```
Error: Failed to write manifest file.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=640 "You can’t save the file “manifest.json” because the volume “Data” is out of space." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX...
  at c(app:///main.jsbundle:1160:3923)
  at map([native code])
  at ? (app:///main.jsbundle:1160:1925)
  at value(app:///main.jsbundle:41:3842)
  at ? (app:///main.jsbundle:41:1163)
  at value(app:///main.jsbundle:41:2799)
  at value(app:///main.jsbundle:41:1133)
  at value([native code])
```

- Device - iPhone 11 Max Pro
- iOS - 14.5
- Sentry SDK - 2.1.0
- Using AsyncStorage as well

Don't have more details on this but checking number of google searches made me confuse. Found that its Apple Privacy issue but same time, I can found its memory issue as error states.

Found same question on expo forum but with no replies. [Issue Link](https://forums.expo.io/t/ios-out-of-space-error-message/39390)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @AlexFenwoodHughes, we moved to storyblok as it is more suitable for our case and didn't get time to check this.

Comment: No worries, but how does Storyblok play in to this?